# NIFI-Remove quotes from the beginning of ID Attribute

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

i have a CSV file which contains ID Column with " in the beginning like

id, name, job, salary, Response

"1,x,y,1000,0"

"2,a,b,1000,1"

"3,q,w,1000,1"

i want to remove the (") from id column and also response column

Comment: sounds like you want to remove all the quotes. simple replacetext with `search = "` and `replacement = <empty>` should work

Answer (score 2):

Add *ReplaceText* processor with the given configuration

[image: ReplaceText Configuration]

I hope this will give you desired output.

Your desired output after flowfile flows through ReplaceText:

[image: Output]

Comment: Hi @BarbarosÖzhan, it depends on which evaluation mode you are using. There are 5 evaluation modes in Line-by-Line : All, First-Line, Last-Line, Except-First-Line, Except-Last-Line. It won't differ if we use All but will only change " in first line if we use First-Line and so on.

Comment: pay attention to the **Maximum Buffer Size** set it appropriately according to your FlowFiles